# Requirement for external x509 certificates signature and key algorithms to be used in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: rsa, hyperledger-fabric, x509, ecdsa

We are trying to setup a test network using certificates provided by the organization (i.e., not generated by `cryptogen` nor by `fabric-ca-server`).
I have re-created the MSP for peer0, by placing all mentioned certificates and keys in the corresponding folder.
When peer0 starts, throughs the following error:

```
2020-10-16 14:33:34.269 UTC [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 001 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2020-10-16 14:33:34.314 UTC [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 002 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2020-10-16 14:33:34.325 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 003 KeyStore opened at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/keystore]...done
2020-10-16 14:33:34.325 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 004 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 005 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts/peer0.supplier.dlt.ericsson.com.cer
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 006 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 007 Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts/root-ca.pem
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 008 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/admincerts
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 009 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/intermediatecerts
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 00a Inspecting file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/intermediatecerts/intermediate-issuing-ca.pem
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 00b Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/tlscacerts
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 00c TLS CA certs folder at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/tlsintermediatecerts] is empty. Skipping.
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 00d Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/crls
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 00e crls folder not found at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 00f Loading NodeOUs
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 010 Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 011 Creating Cache-MSP instance
2020-10-16 14:33:34.326 UTC [msp] loadLocalMSP -> DEBU 012 Created new local MSP
2020-10-16 14:33:34.327 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 013 Setting up MSP instance Org1MSP
2020-10-16 14:33:34.329 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 014 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: Failed importing key with opts [&{true}]: Certificate's public key type not recognized. Supported keys: [ECDSA]
```

It seems that the provided certificates are not supported by Fabric. Is there any suggestion/guideline about the format of certificates to be valid in Fabric?

The used certificate says:

`Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption`

`Subject Public Key Info: Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey`

Answer (score 1):

At Hyperledger Fabric there are only supported the certificates and signatures that are generated using the algorithm ECDSA. You have more information about it at the following [link of Hyperledger Fabric CA](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html).